# How to utilise a newly acquired keyword domain to contribute to an already existing healthy website?

Tags: seo, domains

My client's website has just reached spot 1 for the most valuable keyword. We acquired the domain that was at #1 spot. It's a keyword domain (`targetkeyword.tld`). Just wondering what would be the best way to make use of it.

A permanent redirect or a single page that hyperlinks to the brand website?

Should I be concerned about anything negative associated to this keyword domain (poor backlinks and the fact that this website was down for about one month)?

Comment: Did you reach the number one spot _with_ this newly acquired domain, or without?

Comment: Without this domain, just stuck to the basics. I was at #3 for a long time but just last month the domain at #1 expired (which I ended up buying) and #2 got toppled by our domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A domain name that is just the keywords you optimize for is generally called an "Exact Match Domain" (EMD).   In September 2012, [Google launched an algorithm that prevents EMDs from ranking very highly](http://searchengineland.com/library/google/emd-update) (or at least, not as highly as they once did).

Your choices for an EMD are:

1. Use for your site and redirect your old domain name to it.
2. Use your existing brand URL, and redirect the EMD to it.
3. Create a new site on the EMD.

Google seems to love sites that build brands and value EMD much less than it used to.  Given that, I would be very wary of trying for option #1.

Option #2 would be good if the EMD gets type in traffic.  Otherwise it won't get additional traffic.

Option #3 could be good as long as you don't duplicate content between the sites, but it is a significant amount of work.

Answer (score 1):

How much can one website (potentially one page) with a few links really help? Unless you're creating a whole new website, that would potentially compete with the one you have now, there's not a whole lot to gain. The exception is to use a 301 redirect. Keeping that name is also good so you can keep the competition from doing so.

Comment: Is there any risk associated in case old domain has got some negative factors associated (not that I could find any) and will 301 redirect from a keyword domain be counted actively?

Comment: That is a good question, and to be honest I'm not sure. But I have heard of people giving up on domains and starting over with a new one just because its so hard to remove a domain from being penalized. I would be wary of redirecting it if there are any red flags. Hopefully somebody with more knowledge about that can shine a better light on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

All search engines support keyword oriented domain but should be genuine and closely related to your business/brand.